# Log data. Customize fprintf - C

Tags: c, string, printf, customization, args

I want to customize output to a file from my program.

```
void http_log(char* msg, ...)
{
    char* prePend = "Date-Time: %s === ";//Prepended text
    size_t len1 = strlen(prePend);
    size_t len2 = strlen(msg);
    char *s = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);  //The new string
    memcpy(s, prePend, len1);
    memcpy(s + len1, msg, len2 + 1); // includes terminating null

    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

    char *dateTime = asctime (timeinfo);//Get the current date time
    dateTime[strlen(dateTime) - 1] = 0;//Take away the new line character 

    va_list args;
    va_start( args, msg);

    //I think the problem lies here... 
    fprintf( log_fd, s, dateTime, args);//Print it to the log file. log_fd is already created and opened.
    printf(s, dateTime, args);//Prints to screen. 

    va_end( args);
    free( s);
}
```

I want to add some standard text before the output from http_log(); (The current date in this case). After that i want to add some customizable text that you pass in to the http_log function http_log("This will be appended after the date \n");. and at last i want to be able to use the %s, %d, %ld and so on (Don't know what they are called) like http_log("Connected with IP address %s\n", IP_addres);

My problem is that the values i pass through does not get printed. Should i try to combine the string with the values before i combine the values or... 
Or is there some other other thing that is wrong with my code??

I'm grateful for all the help && || *pointers

Some C fun :)

Comment: Think about the preprocessor and using variadic argument replacements. That might work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass the `va_list args` to `printf()`, but to `vprintf()`.
And you cannot combine an "additional argument" `dateTime` with the `va_list`, 
so you have to print them separately:

```
void http_log(char* msg, ...)
{
    char *dateTime = ...;
    fprintf(log_fd, "Date-Time: %s === ", dateTime);
    printf("Date-Time: %s === ", dateTime);

    va_list args;

    va_start(args, msg);
    vfprintf(log_fd, msg, args);
    va_end( args);

    va_start(args, msg);
    vprintf(msg, args);
    va_end( args);
}
```

Comment: Why not use the preprocessor and variable arguments?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That function writes twice (to log_fd and to stdout), so I assume that a macro solution would not be much simpler or shorter. But I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Maybe. Anyway, you are missing a `va_end`, `va_start` pair between the prints.

Comment: Martin & @Deduplicator: So one should not do `va_start(args, msg);  vfprintf(log_fd, msg, args);  vprintf(msg, args); va_end( args);`?  Is using `args` twice the concern?

Comment: @chux: Yes. See for example http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/stdarg.h.html: The object ap may be passed as an argument to another function; if that function invokes the va_arg() macro with parameter ap, the value of ap in the calling function is unspecified and shall be passed to the va_end() macro prior to any further reference to ap.

Comment: @chux: Yes, because args might be e.g. a pointer to allocated memory, holding some internal state for iteration. That is neccessary on some platforms. That is also the reason `va_end`and `va_copy` are provided at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Face-palm: "the reason `va_end` and `va_copy` are provided at all" makes it so obvious.  Thanks to Martin also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with only one call to `printf()`. Your message and parameters you have to pass to `v` version of the print function, `vfprintf()` in your case. The date (or whatever you want to generate inside `http_log()`) you have to pass to non-`v` version of the print function.